# how to put this idea

Tags: grammar, phrases

Can I say:

> Who you are is not important, with whom you cooperate is important.

I want to know if it is correct in grammar. Is there other better way to express this idea?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Welcome to ELU.SE. Unfortunately proof-reading is [explicitly off-topic](/help/on-topic). Proofreading questions can come in many forms: "Help me fix this", "What's wrong with this", "Are there any mistakes", "Which is correct", but they all involve reading a specific text and won't really help anyone else. **Please identify what you're particularly concerned about, and edit the question to indicate that.** Please see the section "How can ask about checking my text?" in the [Help pages](/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

The two clauses "Who you are is not important" and "with whom you cooperate is important" are two independent clauses (they can both stand alone as whole sentences).
Normally, you need a [conjunction](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/conjunction) to join these.

> e.g. Who you are is not important, **but** with whom you co-operate is important.

This makes sense, but sounds really ugly. Removing the second "important" doesn't really help.

> Who you are is not important, **but** with whom you co-operate is.

---

Alternatively, you could try separating it into two sentences.

> Who you are is not important. With whom you co-operate is important.

This also makes sense, but still sounds too caveman-y in my opinion.

---

After shuffling the word order around for a while, this is the best I could come up with:

> The importance doesn't lie in who you are, but rather with whom you co-operate.

The above sentence works fine, but personally, I would change the wording to make it sound *slightly* less pretentious.

> **What matters is not who you are, but rather the people with whom you work.**

Comment: @user254926 no probem :)